# PL-SQL, Oracle Apex: How can I add pagination to a PL-SQL dynamic content table?

Tags: javascript, html, css, plsql, oracle-apex

I created a PL-SQL dynamic content report in Oracle Apex, however I am having trouble figuring out how to add pagination to it. I have too many rows and therefore adding pagination to the table will provide a better user experience. My sample code looks as follows:

BEGIN

```
htp.p('<table>
  <tr> <th>ID</th> 
  <th>First Name</th> 
      <th>Last Name</th>
  <th>Email</th></tr>'); 

    for i in(select * from exampleTable)
    loop
        
            htp.p('<tr>
                <td>'||i.id||'</td>
                <td>'||i.first_Name||'</td>
                <td>'||i.last_name||'</td>
                <td>'||i.email||'</td>
            </tr>');
    
    end loop;

htp.p('</table>');
```

END;

Comment: Is there a reason that you're putting a report in a table like this rather than using a built-in APEX report (interactive or classic)?  Either of which would have built-in pagination in addition to a number of other usability improvements?

Comment: It's business requirement, in other areas of the website I am using both Interactive reports and classic reports (MediaList, Badge List, Regular classic report with Value attribute Pairs-Column where required), however for this I need a customized table that does not mirror IR or CR look and feel. It needs to be a PL-SQL dynamic content table with pagination.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Create two hidden items on the page, say, `Pxx_START_ROW` and `Pxx_PAGE_SIZE`.
- Modify your query to be paginated.  That will require that you sort the data somehow assuming you want the results to be deterministic.  So rather than

  select *
  from exampleTable

you'd have

```
 select *
   from exampleTable e
  order by e.id
 offset :Pxx_START_ROW rows
  fetch next :Pxx_PAGE_SIZE rows only
```

- Then create a process that updates `Pxx_START_ROW` when you click some sort of a "previous" or "next" button.  You'll probably want to update your dynamic process to generate those buttons because I'd expect you'd want them to be part of the table though functionally you could create those buttons in a different region.

Answer (score 0):

Go to page > JavaScript > File URLs, use this url

```
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/js/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.js
```

Go to page > CSS > File URLs, use this url

```
https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.css
https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.23/css/dataTables.bootstrap4.min.css
```

create a region, region type PLSQL dynamic content

```
begin
htp.p('
<table id="example" class="table table-striped table-bordered" style="width:100%">
    <thead>
        <tr> 
            <th>ID</th> 
            <th>First Name</th> 
            <th>Last Name</th>
            <th>Email</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>'); 

    for i in(select * from exampleTable)
    loop

        htp.p('
        <tr>
            <td>'||i.id||'</td>
            <td>'||i.first_Name||'</td>
            <td>'||i.last_name||'</td>
            <td>'||i.email||'</td>
        </tr>');
    end loop;
    htp.p('
    <tbody>
</table>');
end;
```